# How to get URL query withouth parsing it in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, query-string

Hello everyone I am trying to just get my route with all query params as it is, withouth parsing it.
My route is something like this:

```
http://somewebsite/orders?key1=value1&key=value
```

I don't want to use

@Query()

that returns the object with key/value pairs I just want to get plain string value of everything that is behind ?
so I want to get something like this

```
string = "key1=value1&key=value"
```

edit

controller.ts

```
@Get('/orders')
getOrders(
    @Query(ValidateQueryPipe) query: QueryParameters): Subscription {
    // here I want to have my query as a string not as an object. 
    })
}
```

so when I send a request to my route from let's say postman I will be able to have all the key/value pairs I pass but as a string...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass the [request object](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object) to your function and get the [`originalUrl`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl), where the query string should be located

```js
import { Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';

getOrders(@Req() request: Request): Subscription {
  const regex = /(?<=\?).*$/gm;
  const result = request.originalUrl.match(regex);

  if (result) {
    const query = result[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: OK sorry I maybe I wasn't so clear, I have no idea what queries I am getting I will edit  my question

Comment: @LaCodeM I have tried to change the example for you nestjs, so try it out.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally missed @Req() decorator. Works like a charm!